# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, post, entity-framework-core

Person.cs (сущность персоны):

```
public class Person
    {
        private long _id;

        private string _name;

        private string _displayName;

        private List<Skill> _skills;

        public long Id
        {
            set => _id = value;
            get => _id;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            set => _name = value;
            get => _name;
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            set => _displayName = value;
            get => _displayName;
        }

        public List<Skill> Skills
        {
            set => _skills = value;
            get => _skills;
        }

        public Person(string name, string displayName, List<Skill> skills)
        {
            Name = name;
            DisplayName = displayName;
            Skills = new List<Skill>();
            for (int i = 0; i < skills.Count; i++)
            {
                Skills.Add(new Skill(skills[i].Name, skills[i].Level/*, Id*/));
            }

        }

        private Person() { }
    }
```

Skill.cs (сущность навыка):

```
 public class Skill
    {
        private long _id;

        private string _name;

        private byte _level;

        private long _personId;

        [Key]
        public long Id
        {
            set => _id = value;
            get => _id;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            set => _name = value;
            get => _name;
        }

        public byte Level
        {
            set => _level = value;
            get => _level;
        }

        public long PersonId
        {
            set => _personId = value;
            get => _personId;
        }

        public Skill(string name, byte level)
        {
            Name = name;
            Level = level;
        }
    }
```

POST запрос:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post()
       {
            Skill attentiveness = new Skill ("attentiveness", 2);
            List<Skill> skills = new List<Skill> {attentiveness};
            Person person = new Person("Igor", "newVoitje", skills);

            _context.Skills.Add(attentiveness);
            _context.Persons.Add(person);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

С помощью миграций создаю БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь выполнить POST запрос и вылазит ошибка:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Skills_Persons_PersonId". The conflict occurred in database "DbHallOfFame", table "dbo.Persons", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Обыскал все ресурсы, все равно не могу решить проблему

Comment: При создании Skill вы не указываете PersonId - и ведь это поле а) является обязательным б) должно быть из диапазона уже вставленных записей в таблицу Persons. Добавьте в конструктор ещё один параметр (personId) и думайте, откуда взять его значение.

Comment: @AK ORM: EF Core должен же при добавление в DbSet инициализировать Id'шники, разве нет?

Comment: Вы не договорили фразу: для первичных ключей - да, должен. В таблице Person поле Id является первичным ключом, вставлять не надо. А в таблице Skills поле Id  является первичным ключом, его заполнять не надо. А вот поле PersonId в Skills является внешним (foreign) ключом к таблице Person и его автоматическую вставку EF не обязан делать, только контролировать проверку.

Comment: @AK но раз генерация Person.Id происходить при инициализации, то мне придется после добавление в таблицу вытаскивать Person.Id и присваивать Skills.PersonId. Вроде странный подход

Comment: Вроде странный подход? Ну, изначально вопрос был не о странности, а о том, что не так и что делать. Так вот о том, что делать. Вам надо сначала создать Person (после добавления всех полей сделать SaveChanges, который заполнит сущности Person Id) и после этого прописать этот Id в Skills (неважно, с конструктора контролируя инварианты или через сеттер) и ещё раз сделать SaveChanges. По хорошему ещё и обернуть в транзакцию. У вас в коде ещё бомбы есть, но поговорим об этом когда рванёт, если рванёт.